# Displaying database details on a datagrid

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, wpf, datagrid

I am trying to display my database details on a datagrid using the following methods. I am able to establish connection with the database and do updates so that's all fine. Just having issues with displaying the data after making a query.

The first method query below does the query. I am trying to use that info and run the codes under the 2nd method which is called when I click a button.

I am having problem callign my query method. I was under the impression I can call it under adapter.SelectCommand but that returns an error saying "cannot implicitly convert type". Please advice if I am running the query wrongly. Thanks.

```
public MySqlDataReader Query(string queryString)
        {     
            MySqlDataReader reader;
            MySqlCommand cmd2;

            try
            {
                cmd2 = new MySqlCommand(queryString, conn); 
                reader = cmd2.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(reader.GetInt32(0) + " " + reader.GetString(1) + " " + reader.GetDouble(2));
                }
                return reader;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error in query");
                Console.Read(); 
            }
            return null;
        }

private void Button_Retrieve(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
                adapter.SelectCommand = dataSource.Query("SELECT * FROM PERSONS WHERE Name = 'Sam';");//THis line returns the error
                DataTable dt = new DataTable("PERSONS"); 
                adapter.Fill(dt);
                dataGrid1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
                adapter.Update(dt);
            } 
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(error.StackTrace);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Whats dataSource.Query? Seems like it doesnt return an MySqlCommand.

Comment: it is the first method Query() mentioned above. It is in another class and dataSource is the instance of that class thus calling it this way.

Comment: If i get your code correctly you dont need the adapter any way when all you want is get a datareader into a datatable, just use the load method from datatable it has a parameter of datareader. http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.datatable.load(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your adapter does not have a connection

```
// Assumes that connection is a valid SqlConnection object.
string queryString = 
  "SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName FROM dbo.Customers";
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, connection);

DataSet customers = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(customers, "Customers");
```

Comment: Tnks for reply. SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, connection); is a repeated set of codes considering I have already established that in the Query method. Was trying to use the return value of Query directly.

Comment: connection (in my case conn) is sitting in a different class same as my Query method. I just want to call Query method on my mainWindow class without having to call conn again. My Button_Retrieve method is at the mainWindow class.

Comment: Your way works but like I said, can I just do it by just calling Query method? Tnks.

Comment: What part of you your adapter does not have a connection is not clear?  It cannot magically use a connection you have not supplied to it.